# pocketsphinx recognizer.py has initial incorrect output

Tags: ros, pocketsphinx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using pocketsphinx and it works great for recognition.  However, when recognizer.py first starts, it outputs one or two random words from the dictionary, as if there was a queue that has to be cleared.  This happens even if the microphone is muted.  Any idea where that might be originating?  Is there some way to suppress that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/112446/pocketsphinx-recognizer.py-has-initial-incorrect-output/) by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 875 on 2013-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've not seen this before -- but I imagine it is likely an issue with either gstreamer or the VADAR gstreamer plugin which is used to segment the audio input. There's currently no built in options to handle such a problem, but it could probably be easily added by storing the time at which the pipeline was enabled and making sure that some time as passed when an utterance arrives.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-12-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dan](https://answers.ros.org/users/144/dan/) on 2013-12-23**:
OK, I'll try that.